# Getting 'pips' slider value into a textbox

Tags: jquery, html

Good day everyone

The problem is this. If I use the Jquery 'generic' slider I can transfer the value of the slider to a textbox with this code

```
$("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val(ui.value);
```

But I want to use the slightly more funky slider with 'pips' (for pips read numbers showing on your slider!). Despite a big Google search and monkeying with it for ages I can't find a way of getting the slider value into my textbox using this new slider. Below is the whole page of code (HTML and Jquery)

If anyone has any ideas I would very much appreciate the help

Thanks

Peter

```html
 <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Slider_pips.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    
    
    <title>Slider testing with pips</title>

       
<link href="Styles/jquery-ui-slider-pips.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!-- include the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-slider-pips.js" type="text/javascript"></script>              


<!-- plus a jQuery UI theme, here I use "flick" -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css"/>

    <style type="text/css">
        .slider
        {
            width: 740px;
        }
    </style>


</head>



<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

     <!-- Added for spacing at the top of the page - PW -->

    <p />
    
    <br />



    <!-- This is number 1 slider - PW -->
    
    <div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Slider 1 value"></asp:Label>  
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 16px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

    <br />

<div class="slider"></div>

    </div>

    <br />




    <!-- This is number 2 slider - PW -->

    <div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Slider 2 value"></asp:Label> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="margin-left: 16px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

    <br />

<div class="slider"></div>

    </div>

    <br />



    <!-- This is number 3 slider - PW -->


    <div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Slider 3 value"></asp:Label>  
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" style="margin-left: 16px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />

    <br />

<div class="slider"></div>

    </div>

    <br />
    


    <!-- This is number 4 slider - PW -->
    

   <div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Slider 4 value"></asp:Label>  
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" style="margin-left: 16px"></asp:TextBox>
       <br />

    <br />

<div class="slider"></div>

    </div>

    <br />

    <!-- This is number 5 slider - PW -->


   <div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Slider 5 value"></asp:Label> &nbsp;<asp:TextBox 
           ID="TextBox5" runat="server" style="margin-left: 16px"></asp:TextBox>
       <br />

    <br />

<div class="slider"></div>

    </div>

    <br />




    <!-- Need to add the input function even if the textboxes are hidden, also need to duplicate 5 times - PW -->


        <script type="text/javascript">

     $(".slider").slider().slider("pips");
         
    $(".slider").slider({
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
        step: 1
           
    })

    .slider("pips", {
       
        rest: "label"
       
    });

        </script>





    </form>
    
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference; you just use the `onslidechange` event as you would without the the pips plugin :)

If you heck out the documentation example page: http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#styling-emoji the JS code for the emoji slider basically shows you how to do it, but not using a textbox.

```
$(".slider").on("slidechange", function( e, ui ) { 
    $txtbox.val( ui.value ) 
});
```

Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Simon

Many thanks for your help, I was struggling with that (I'm a pretty new programmer)  - for anyone else that needs it this is how I moved the value to an ASP text box using a variation of the solution Simon gave.

```
  <script>

    $(".slider").on("slidechange", function( e, ui ) {
        $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val(ui.value) 
   });


   </script>
```

Thanks again I appreciate your time Simon

Peter

Comment: No problem :) -- please consider marking the question as answered, it helps SEO and others with the same question.